# Manually removing bulk components from cut tape?

Tags: components

I ordered a bulk quantity of components for experimentation and they were shipped in a cut tape format.

I've been removing components individually from the tape but it requires a large amount of labor, removal of tape residue from the leads, etc.

Is there a better method?

[image: Cut tape picture]

Comment: Ah, through hole components in tape. What a pain. How many components are we talking about? Can't be many if it's for experimentation.

Comment: What kind of component have you got?  A picture of the tape with components could help here.

Comment: If it's a radial electrolytic capacitor like that, you can make leads slightly different length as you cut them.  That way you will have an extra bit of polarity coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top tape should just peel back, and should allow you to dump the components on the table. I have never heard of tape residue on the leads.

If there is such residue, you could either bathe them in an electronic cleaning solution (3M Novec comes to mind) or just cut the residue parts off, if the leads are long enough.

**EDIT:**
I just realized you are talking about through hole components. Most of the time, I have never needed to clean them, as we cut the leads after they are soldered into the board, and you can just let the residue part be. An easy way to prep the components is when you are about to solder, apply some flux from a flux pen, and that should clean the surface so that you can solder it. 3M Novec would also work too on this as well.

For reference to others, this is what I believe that you are referring to.
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am dealing with.  I expected I could just peel the tape or pull the components out but the tape was so secure that I had to score the leads with a knife in order to remove a few and that left the residue.

Comment: Wow, talk about poor packaging. Soak the tape in a (non conducting) liquid then pull the components out?

Answer (score 18):

For leaded components on tape, I'd just cut the component leads at the tape - you very rarely need the full lead length.

Comment: That's so obvious I would have never thought of doing it the easy way!

Comment: You can often use scissors rather than diagonal cutters, so you don't have to cut one lead at a time.

Comment: This works but loses the polarisation information in different lead lengths (seen in the top image), so only suitable for when you're immediately inserting it into a board.

Comment: Those electrolytic caps have a polarization marking on the part. I don't know of any parts where polarization is shown only by the length of the leads.

Answer (score 2):

I just cut them to avoid any adhesive residue (but usually THT caps can be had in bags of 500, and similarly for TO-92 parts).

You're losing information on the capacitors by cutting them though, unless you leave the positive lead longer.

The case is marked so it's not a huge deal, but having the leads a consistent length and the positive longer to aim at the silk-screen target shaves fractions of a second off of hand stuffing.

Answer (score 1):

I get a lot of transistors, and resistors that are on tape.  Goof off softens the tape nicely and vinegar helps to get rid of the glue.  Old stock components are harder and require overnight soaking, so I use 2 parts water to 1 part windex for that

Answer (score 1):

I would heat up and soften the adhesive between the two layers of the tape. You may use a heat gun or a hair dryer. Once the tape gets warm enough, pull the upper side tape away while holding the parts. Now, the parts can fall off from the tape at once. (You may use alcohol to clean the remaining adhesive on the leads of the capacitors.)